# Sizing of Samba Linux Server

Tags: samba, performance, cache, ram, buffer

Do you know any performance of sizing recommendations about Samba 4.7.1 ?

For few informations :

2vCPUs / 1 Core
8GB of RAM
140 simultaneous Windows users / 250 at most /
20 NFS volumes mounted via fstab

This question because my RAM is all eated up by the buffer/cache (normal according to last chapter of : https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Performance_Tuning).

Users are not complaining but I don't know if the servers is needing more or less.

Comment: What are the load average numbers for the box?  Is any/much swap being used?

Comment: True, I forgot to give those points :
The load average is 0.04, 0.06, 0.06.
Near no swap usage : 96 kib used

CPU and RAM on top's graph look really calm

Comment: Then you don't have any issues... use of buffer/cache is a normal thing, as long as you aren't swapping (excessively) or experiencing high I/O wait times (what the load average measures) you are good to go.

Comment: It sounds really logic, this is a good way to audit that. Thanks for it.